# passing variable value from javascript to php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am working on a project where I used ajax for asynchronous DB access.
I store the value in JavaScript variable as follows..

```
var content=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

now what I wanted is to pass this value to the php module on same page..
Please suggest me..its urgent

Comment: Make another Ajax call to send the data. There are tons of related questions (this one is asked a lot). Check the right hand column on this page.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make a separate AJAX request to another script to achieve this. PHP is server-sided and therefore cannot directly interact with the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the data (which you are assigning to content) in PHP because, as the other answers here tell you, PHP is server-side and JavaScript is on the client. If you are getting this data from a page you control, instead of `var content = xhr.responseText;` just modify the data BEFORE you send it. For example, if you are making an AJAX call to a `process.php` file on your server to get the data you are otherwise assigning to `content` in JavaScript, be sure to handle the data in process.php PRIOR to echo()'ing the data (which you are then storing inside `content` on the client):

In process.php:

```
// below is the normal server script which you are storing in content on the client
// echo $result;
// instead, we are going to operate on the data first:
return doSomething($result);
```

Then on the client:

```
var newContent = xhr.responseText;
```

And the `newContent` variable will contain the data you previously wished to modify with PHP. If you DO NOT have control of the server script which you are calling with AJAX, then as mentioned here already, you will need to send a SECOND AJAX call to the server with your PHP, and use `$_GET` or `$_POST` to retrieve that `content` data and then play with it there.

Answer (score 0):

Am unclear about your need to pass value from javascript to php.

But I can give you,

1. A non-recommended but working approach towards your problem:
   You said, you are making an Ajax call at first. While processing the corresponding server side php function, Store the response value (value of xmlhttp.responseText) into a **$_SESSION** variable. Finally Reload the page (using location.reload()) inside the ajax response handler function.
2. And a recommended approach towards your problem:
   You might have added some if-else control-flow structures in the php code and expecting to execute them after getting the ajax response value (sadly you cannot do that). So if you do have some logic like that, then convert those if-else conditions to corresponding Javascript code. May be a javascript function and call that function by passing the ajax response value to it. This new function will use your ajax response value and make changes in some parts of your webpage by applying necessary logic.